# Resize and drag Image

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can anyone suggest the script for Image Resize with drag?

But I want the script with the handles associated with Image so we can resize and drag Image.
(Like Div Resizing).

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the image height 100% and width 100% and put it in the div that you download it from this [link](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/genresize/genresize.html)

Comment: what do you mean ?! ... you can resize it by dragging it from the Angle , the top ,the right , the bottom or the lift

Comment: FYI, it's considered best practice to include more info on the resource being linked in case that link no longer works in the future.